# Trying to render html in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic2

I'm trying to render an html string so that it displays links, etc using Ionic. This is my very first Ionic app.

```
<ion-content class="home">
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let f of item">
    <h2 class="question" style="white-space:initial;" ng-bind-html="{{f.question}}">{{f.question}}</h2>
    <p class="answer" style="white-space:initial;" ng-bind-html="{{f.answer}}">{{f.answer}}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I've tried ng-bind-html as above and it's saying...

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'ng-bind-html' since it isn't a known property of 'h2'. ("

I've also tried ng-bind-html-safe but that produces the same error.
Without the ng-bind-html code, the string is displayed but with the html characters not being interpreted.

Also, here is the code coming from the .ts file

```
  this.faqService.load()
  .then(data1 => { 
    this.item = data1;
  });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding

Comment: ng-bind-html is in angular 1. not sure why you need to bind in your example though.

Comment: So what is the replacement in 2?

Comment: check the link you just do `<p [innerHTML]="{{f.answer}}">
</p>`

Comment: using [innerHTML]="{{f.answer}}"> throws the following error:

Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{f.answer}}] in Faq@26:25 ("
      <h2 class="question">{{f.question}}</h2>

      <p class="answer"  [ERROR ->][innerHTML]="{{f.answer}}">{{f.answer}}</p>

Comment: ohk try `<p [innerHTML]="f.answer"> </p>`

Comment: Yes... <p [innerHTML]="f.answer"></p> works. Thank you @suraj

Answer (score 4):

The answer to my question is

```
<p [innerHTML]="f.answer"></p>
```

Hope this helps other newbies to Angular 2 / Ionic.

Comment: This allows for cross site scripting You should use it very sparingly.